# Vite and dealing with require vs import (for google api)

Tags: node.js, google-api, vite

First time using Vite with google apis and right at the start ran into trouble trying to import the translation client. It uses 'require' to import it  `const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate')` instead of 'import' syntax. I've tried workarounds including the vite require plugin but nothing has worked (reworking it into an import statement causes different errors with 'process not defined' which just stumped me even more) and it seems strange that no one else seems to mention any problem with vite and google apis. Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Setup is really simple.
Just create new vite project and try to import anything from `@google-cloud`

You get an error [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomKy.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

according to: https://web3auth.io/community/t/vite-class-heritage-is-not-an-object-or-null/5574
for vite < 5 solutions is importing like this:

```
const { Web3Auth } = await import('@web3auth/modal/dist/modal.umd.min');
```

for me this did not work either with vite 4.2 and I have a similar error importing googleapis.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
import TranslationServiceClient from "@google-cloud/translate";
```

Comment: Yes but that led to another rabbit hole of errors. Started giving me 'process not defined', tried fixing it by defining it in the vite.config.js, and that lead to more errors with something about buffers and at that point I had no idea what was going on anymore. My app is extremely barebones so there should be no conflicts with any other settings or libraries.

Comment: Going to need some more information, maybe a repo or setup instructions that you did?